# Image slider or carousel that handles different image sizes

Tags: slider, carousel

NivoSlider, Flexslider, and others all require the images to be the same width and height.  I need a slider that will allow me to have images with varying widths.

http://www.sasaki.com/ has a good example, but it only works if you have the slider take up the full width of the screen.

Any direction would be **greatly greatly** appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

RoyalSlider fits the bill. It accommodates different size images.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html

> Touch enabled jQuery plugin that lets you create beautiful responsive
>   carousel slider.